# How do I ensure that all the images are aligned correctly in differing browser windows/resolutions?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Firstly, there are 3 separate images. A chick, the word 'delivery' and 'foodstant' I wanted to align them in such a way--> [3 images](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/index1.png)
Are there any methods to achieve such positioning which enables an unchanged position despite the resizing of the browser window and perhaps resolution ?

Both Absolute and relative positioning works, but resizing the browser screws up everything. 
Margins can't seem to do the trick.. Or I am just less-skilled.

HTML code as follows:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title> Foodstant Delivery </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylo.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>

<figure>
<img id="del" src="images/delivery12.png" alt="Delivery" />
<img id="foo" src="images/foostant2.png" alt="Foodstant" />
<img id="chi" src="images/logochick.png" alt="Chick" />
</figure>

<nav id="hnavbar">
    <ul id="hli">
        <li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a id="cu"   href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a id="au"   href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a id="tc"   href="TC.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
        <li><a id="job"  href="jobs.html" target="_blank">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a id="yo"   href="order.html">Your Order</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>

</body>
```

CSS code as follows

```
/* Foodstant Delivery */

* {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
  }
 body { font-family: 'Comic Sans MS',Verdana,Helvetica,Courier New,sans-serif;
background:url("images/bg.jpg");    
   }
   /* home page */
  #hnavbar{
font-size:2em;
margin-top:-13em;
}
  #hnavbar ul li {
    list-style-type:none;       
    width:325px;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 13px 0 13px; 
    }
  #chi {
position:relative;
top:-30em;
left:10em;
       }
  #foo {
position:relative;
top:1em;
left:-11em;
   }
  #del {
position:relative;
top:10.5em;
left:26em;
}
 /* home page */
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the values for top and left in percents as opposed to 'em'. These percentages would be relative to the parent element containing these image.  OR simply use one single image instead of 3 and use a image map. Here s a coupla online tools to do this:

http://www.mobilefish.com/services/image_map/image_map.php 
http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: The parent element for the images in this case is <figure> ?

Comment: It's a HTML5 element for marking up images, illustrations etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something very similar to this and after some time I decided I had to use absolute positioning to every link. The problem with your code is that it seems that you don't quite understand how relative and absolute positioning works. Absolute objects are always relative to it's nearer parent set to "relative position". So you should try this:

```
#hnavbar { position: relative; } //all "absolute" children will be relative to this hnavbar
#home, #menu, ... { position: absolute; }
```

And after that, you should set the position of every absolute positioned menu link with top/left or bottom/right properties.

For the image, if you don't have links for "Foodstant" and "Delivery", I would really use one single image.

Hope it helps!